# SharPoint 2010 wsp deployment is too slow in a server farm environment

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-deployment

In the beginning, We have 1 Application Servers, 2 Web Front End Servers and database server in Asia.
Deploying solution(wsp file) is fast.
After adding a WFE server in Sweden to the farm,deploying solution(wsp files) becomes very very slow.
It cost more then 5 hours to deploy. We have adjust TimeZone but it still not work.
Does anyone know the reason why deployment is so slow or
is there a way to detect the deployment process?

Comment: What's the connection speed and latency between your swedish and asian portion of the farm?

Comment: check Cumulatives Updates and Service Pack on each WFE. Make sure all web front end is running the same build of SharePoint